# Token validation issue

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

**Why does this error occur when I do request? How to fix it?** *WSO2 4.1.0*

I don't understand where to look for the problem, this URL is nowhere to be found.
Who can suggest something?

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-09-18 02:12:30,642] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.jwt.JWTValidatorImpl} - Error while parsing JWT org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException: URI does not specify a valid host name: https:9443/oauth2/jwks
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.determineTarget(CloseableHttpClient.java:95)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.JWTUtil.retrieveJWKSConfiguration_aroundBody0(JWTUtil.java:58)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.JWTUtil.retrieveJWKSConfiguration(JWTUtil.java:52)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.jwt.JWTValidatorImpl.retrieveJWKSet_aroundBody22(JWTValidatorImpl.java:227)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.jwt.JWTValidatorImpl.retrieveJWKSet(JWTValidatorImpl.java:224)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.jwt.JWTValidatorImpl.validateSignature_aroundBody8(JWTValidatorImpl.java:145)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.jwt.JWTValidatorImpl.validateSignature(JWTValidatorImpl.java:135)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.jwt.JWTValidatorImpl.validateToken_aroundBody0(JWTValidatorImpl.java:62)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.jwt.JWTValidatorImpl.validateToken(JWTValidatorImpl.java:57)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.jwt.JWTValidationServiceImpl.validateJWTToken_aroundBody0(JWTValidationServiceImpl.java:44)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.jwt.JWTValidationServiceImpl.validateJWTToken(JWTValidationServiceImpl.java:36)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.jwt.JWTValidator.getJwtValidationInfo_aroundBody32(JWTValidator.java:691)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.jwt.JWTValidator.getJwtValidationInfo(JWTValidator.java:659)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.jwt.JWTValidator.authenticate_aroundBody0(JWTValidator.java:174)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.jwt.JWTValidator.authenticate(JWTValidator.java:142)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.oauth.OAuthAuthenticator.authenticate_aroundBody4(OAuthAuthenticator.java:301)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.oauth.OAuthAuthenticator.authenticate(OAuthAuthenticator.java:111)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.isAuthenticate_aroundBody56(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:522)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.isAuthenticate(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:516)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.handleRequest_aroundBody46(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:402)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.handleRequest(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:353)
at org.apache.synapse.api.API.process(API.java:403)
at org.apache.synapse.api.AbstractApiHandler.apiProcessNonDefaultStrategy(AbstractApiHandler.java:107)
at org.apache.synapse.api.AbstractApiHandler.identifyAPI(AbstractApiHandler.java:127)
at org.apache.synapse.api.AbstractApiHandler.dispatchToAPI(AbstractApiHandler.java:59)
at org.apache.synapse.api.rest.RestRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RestRequestHandler.java:90)
at org.apache.synapse.api.rest.RestRequestHandler.process(RestRequestHandler.java:76)
at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:54)
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:344)
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:101)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:376)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:190)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify your JWKS configurations in the `deployment.toml` as shown below.

```
[[apim.jwt.issuer]]
name = "https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token"
jwks.url = "https://localhost:9443/oauth2/jwks"

[[apim.jwt.issuer]]
name = "wso2is"
jwks.url = "https://localhost:9445/oauth2/jwks"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes an empty `hostname` in deployment.toml could be the cause of this error

```
[server]
hostname = ""
node_ip = "$env{NODE_IP}"
base_path = "https://$ref{server.hostname}:${carbon.management.port}"

[transport.https.properties]
proxyPort = 443
```

To prove that its your problem you can go to `https://<host>:<port>/carbon` console and then check your values inside

Idenity -> Identity Providers -> Resident -> Inbound Authentication Configuration -> OAuth2/OpenID Connect Configuration

There you should see your `https:9443/oauth2/jwks` becouse of your initial hostname value.